# Лучший способ для запуска длительного (асинхронного) процесса (Asp.NET 4)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Ситуация такая: есть страница и есть парсер информации. Он может обрабатывать данные несколько часов. Разумеется, что пользователь не будет находится все это время на странице.
Поэтому хотелось бы запустить процесс и иметь доступ к его состоянию, дабы остановить его.

Приходит на ум городушка из исполняемого файла (не выяснил еще, на виртуальном windows-хостинге получится ли) и записи состояния: запущен, остановлен и ход выполнения. Но как остановить это исполнение? Опять же приходит на ум сделать файлик "stop.txt" и проверять его наличие из исполняемого файла, если он появился — удалять и выходить. В общем кажется я изобретаю велосипед.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет о процессах, а в вопросе именно они, то я бы сделал виндоус службу, которая будет заниматься "парсингом". Запускать и останавливать её довольно просто одной строкой кода, также с определением статуса. Взаимодействие между сервером и службой можно сделать при помощи сокетов, например. Возможен вариант с хостингом обоих частей системы на разных серверах. Путем запуска нескольких служб можно увеличить мощность или распараллелить процесс парсинга (если это возможно).

Склоняюсь все-таки к тому, что автору будет достаточно многопоточности.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно кажется. Читайте на MSDN про многопоточное программирование, в частности, про тип `Task`.